# Printing the data from 2 different lists and their index

Tags: python, csv, iterator

I am reading a CSV file this way:

```
import csv

with open('X.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    objectids = []
    municodes = []


    for row in readCSV:
        objectid = row[2]
        municode = row[5]
        objectids.append(objectid)
        municodes.append(municode)
```

Then I would like to print on the screen something like rowlinenumber, "objectids", and "municodes". I tried this way:
checkfirstline = 0

```
for uniqueobjid in objectids:
    if checkfirstline is not 0: #to jump the first line (on this data it's a header)
        print("obdid: " + str(uniqueobjid) + " -- city: " )
    else:
        checkfirstline += 1
```

My problem is that I am not sure how to get the rowlinenumber (index) and the "municodes" from the same position.

I was expecting a result +- like this:

```
row:0 ;  obdid: 3; cityid: 20
row:1 ;  obdid: 4; cityid: 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `csv.reader` is an iterator, you can call `next` on it once to "skip" the header:

```
with open('X.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(readCSV)
    # as before
```

Then use `enumerate` with `zip` when iterating your lists:

```
for idx, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(objectids, municodes)):
    print(f'row:{idx}; obdid: {a}; cityid: {b}')
```

For readability and performance, we use f-strings, available in Python 3.6+.